# Marketing Cloud Connect User Persmission Sets

Tags: permission-sets, marketing-cloud-connect

When setting up the connector which users should be assigned to which permission set in Sales Cloud?

- What permission set would a view only user need?
- What permission set would a content creator and triggered email sender need?

[image]

Comment: if anyone is able to help answer what the differences between these permission sets are? As I cannot find any documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the setup process in Sales Cloud for the MC connect, there is a "manage users" tab within the Marketing Cloud Connector Settings.

This will bring up the following table below, where one can select which users should be Admins or Users. This will automatically add the Sales Cloud user's to the corresponding permission set listed in the question above.

[image]